# Can I set Storm nimbus cluster

Tags: apache-storm

I read some articles that said storm nimbus cannot setup multiple instances. Is that true? Can I start two nimbus instances? if one nimbus died, the other  one will continue provide the service

Comment: What articles did you read that in?

Comment: Seems like apache-storm community will release 1.0.0 version within this Month, and it will contain nimbus(master node) HA feature. check this out, http://www.slideshare.net/ptgoetz/the-future-of-apache-storm.

Comment: Thanks for your answer